# How to open file in gtk c

Tags: c, gtk

This is my code for trying to open a txt file into a textbuffer in gtk. However I get these errors, either segmentation fault or the text never appears.
It prints -

**Open fileSuccess
/Users/me/Desktop/test.txt1This is the text file.
zsh: segmentation fault  ./arduino
(arduino:60001): Gtk-CRITICAL gtk_text_buffer_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer)' failed**

So it reads in the data properly just never sets it to buffer which makes me think there's something wrong here

```
//buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(&view));
//buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);

gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, contents, -1);
```

```
void open_file(GtkTextBuffer *buffer, GtkWindow *widget, GtkWidget *view) {
    g_print("Open file");
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    GtkFileChooserAction action = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;
    gint res;
    GError *error;
    gboolean read_file_status;
    gchar *contents;

    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",
                                          widget,
                                          action,
                                          ("_Cancel"),
                                          GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                          ("_Open"),
                                          GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                          NULL);

    res = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT) {
        g_print("Success\n");
        char *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
        g_print("%s",filename);
        read_file_status = g_file_get_contents(filename,&contents,NULL, &error);
        g_print("%d", read_file_status);
        
        if (read_file_status == FALSE) {
            g_error("error opening file: %s\n",error && error->message ? error->message : "No Detail");
            return;
        }
        g_print("%s", contents);
        //buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(&view));
        //buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);

        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, contents, -1);

    }

    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}
```

```
How I use it in my code.

    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    
    void update_statusbar(GtkTextBuffer *buffer,
                      GtkStatusbar  *statusbar) {
      gchar *msg;
      gint row, col;
      GtkTextIter iter;
      
      gtk_statusbar_pop(statusbar, 0);
    
      gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark(buffer,
          &iter, gtk_text_buffer_get_insert(buffer));
    
      row = gtk_text_iter_get_line(&iter);
      col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset(&iter);
    
      msg = g_strdup_printf("Col: %d Ln: %d", col+1, row+1);
    
      gtk_statusbar_push(statusbar, 0, msg);
    
      g_free(msg);
    }
    
    void on_button_clicked() {
     
        g_print("clicked");
    }
    
    void save_file(GtkTextBuffer *buffer, gpointer data) {
        g_print("Save File");
    
        }
    
    char *get_text_of_textview(GtkWidget *text_view) {
        GtkTextIter start, end;
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer((GtkTextView *)text_view);
        gchar *text;
        gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(buffer, &start, &end);
        text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(buffer, &start, &end, FALSE);
        return text;
    }
    
    void run_code(GtkWidget *text_view) {
        g_print("Run code");
        g_print("%s",get_text_of_textview(text_view));
        
    }
    
    void open_file(GtkTextBuffer *buffer, GtkWindow *widget, GtkWidget *view) {
        g_print("Open file");
        GtkWidget *dialog;
        GtkFileChooserAction action = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;
        gint res;
        GError *error;
        gboolean read_file_status;
        gchar *contents;
    
        dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",
                                              widget,
                                              action,
                                              ("_Cancel"),
                                              GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                              ("_Open"),
                                              GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                              NULL);
    
        res = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
        if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT) {
            g_print("Success\n");
            char *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
            g_print("%s",filename);
            read_file_status = g_file_get_contents(filename,&contents,NULL, &error);
            g_print("%d", read_file_status);
            
            if (read_file_status == FALSE) {
                g_error("error opening file: %s\n",error && error->message ? error->message : "No Detail");
                return;
            }
            g_print("%s", contents);
            //buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(&view));
            //buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
    
            gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, contents, -1);
    
        }
    
        gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
    }
    
    void new_file() {
        g_print("New file");
    }
    
    void mark_set_callback(GtkTextBuffer *buffer,
        const GtkTextIter *new_location, GtkTextMark *mark, gpointer data) {
                           
      update_statusbar(buffer, GTK_STATUSBAR(data));
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
      //Widgets
      GtkWidget *window;
      GtkWidget *vbox;
      
      GtkWidget *toolbar;
      GtkWidget *text_view;
      GtkWidget *statusbar;
      GtkToolItem *exit;
      GtkToolItem *newTb;
      GtkToolItem *openTb;
      GtkToolItem *saveTb;
      GtkToolItem *separator;
      GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    
        
      gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    
      //Window
      window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
      gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 580);
      gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Arduino IDE");
        
      //Vbox
      vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
    
      //Toolbar
      toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new();
      gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS);
        
      //Toolbar Buttons
        
      //Newfile
      newTb = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_NEW);
      gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), newTb, -1);
    
      //Open File
      openTb = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_OPEN);
      gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), openTb, -1);
    
      //Save file
      saveTb = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_SAVE);
      gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), saveTb, -1);
    
      separator = gtk_separator_tool_item_new();
      gtk_tool_item_set_expand(GTK_TOOL_ITEM(separator), TRUE);
      gtk_separator_tool_item_set_draw(GTK_SEPARATOR_TOOL_ITEM(separator), FALSE);
    
      //Quit
      exit = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_QUIT);
      gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), exit, -1);
    
      gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), toolbar, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
        
      //TextView
      text_view = gtk_text_view_new();
      gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view), GTK_WRAP_WORD);
      gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), text_view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      gtk_widget_grab_focus(text_view);
        
      //Buffer
      //buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
      buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view));
      //gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "//The Arduino IDE in C\n\n int main(void) { \n\n }", -1);
    
      //Status-Bar
      statusbar = gtk_statusbar_new();
      gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), statusbar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        
      //Button Actions
    
      //Quit button Action
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(newTb), "clicked",
              G_CALLBACK(new_file), NULL);
        
      //Save button Action
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(saveTb), "clicked",
          G_CALLBACK(save_file), NULL);
        
      //Quit button Action
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(exit), "clicked",
            G_CALLBACK(run_code), NULL);
    
      //Open button Action
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(openTb), "clicked",
          G_CALLBACK(open_file), buffer, 0);
    
      g_signal_connect(buffer, "changed",
            G_CALLBACK(update_statusbar), statusbar);
    
      g_signal_connect_object(buffer, "mark_set",
            G_CALLBACK(mark_set_callback), statusbar, 0);
    
      //Close Window Action
      g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
            G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    
      gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    
      update_statusbar(buffer, GTK_STATUSBAR(statusbar));
    
      gtk_main();
    
      return 0;

}
```

Comment: Show how you create/prepare the `*buffer` variable before passing it in `open_file(GtkTextBuffer *buffer, GtkWindow *widget, GtkWidget *view)`

Comment: Show this information edited into your original post, in the context of how it is actually used, and preferably with a [mcve].  It looks like you are creating buffer initialized to `NULL`, but I do not see where memory is allocated.  Maybe once you place all of this into the post, it will make sense.

Comment: @ryyker i added it all in for you - not sure how to pass through my buffer or how to define it.

Comment: I do not see where you verify that this call is successful?  `buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view));`

Comment: It works for the counting lines and columns function, how would I verify that call?

Comment: It should be checked in the very next line after allocating its memory.  eg: `buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view));` `if(buffer) {...} //checking for null before continuing`

Comment: `  if (buffer = NULL){
        g_print("buffer is null")
    }`?

Comment: Surely the buffer works here though as it is being recognised by the counting lines function - its the passing it through to being replaced by the text file that seems to be the issue @ryyker

Comment: **(arduino:60386): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:55:36.308: gtk_text_buffer_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer)' failed** thats the error

Comment: Where in your post does this error occur?  Show the line

Comment: in the open file function gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, contents, -1);

Comment: where contents is defined as this         char *filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog));
        g_print("%s",filename);
        read_file_status = g_file_get_contents(filename,&contents,NULL, &error);
        g_print("%d", read_file_status);

Comment: Are you certain that in `gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, contents, -1);` that the contents of the buffer at this point is null terminated?, i.e, from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-new) it states that _"If len is -1, text must be nul-terminated. "_

Comment: this is the text file contents - This is the text file.

Comment: still get the same issue **This is the text file.\0

(arduino:60479): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:04:56.323: gtk_text_buffer_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_TEXT_BUFFER (buffer)' failed**

Comment: What status do you see here: `read_file_status = g_file_get_contents(filename,&contents,NULL, &error);
        g_print("%d", read_file_status);`  Is `contents` properly populated?

Comment: i get this 1This is the text file.\0 - where 1 is the read_file_status and This is the text file.\0 is the contents so that all seems good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224679/discussion-between-ryyker-and-christian).

Comment: "`if (buffer = NULL){ g_print("buffer is null") }`" No... Realise that `=` and `==` are different operators. `=` assigns. You seem to want `==` to test equality.

Comment: A different remark is that this normally shouldn't compile: `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(openTb), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(open_file), buffer, 0);`, as this macro has only 4 arguments. Your callback signatures are also completely wrong

Comment: what's the proper call for using this and passing through the buffer? @nielsdg